# Use CSR/JSLink to hide Fields in New/Edit Form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, form, jslink

JSLink don't work for me in this case, can some body say is this Code below ok.

```
    (function () {
    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://teamsite/_catalogs/masterpage/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>'));
    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"><\/script>'));
    var hiddenFiledContext = {};
    hiddenFiledContext.Templates = {}; 
    hiddenFiledContext.Templates.OnPostRender = hiddenFiledOnPreRender;
    hiddenFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "Field1": {
            "NewForm": hiddenFiledTemplate,
            "EditForm": hiddenFiledTemplate
        }
    };  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(hiddenFiledContext);
})();
function hiddenFiledTemplate() {
    return "<span class='csrHiddenField'></span>";
}
function hiddenFiledOnPreRender(ctx) {
    jQuery(".csrHiddenField").closest("tr").hide();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What's the expected and actual result? Any errors thrown?

Comment: No errors, it must hide `Field1` in **NewForm** and **EditForm** on a List View. But nothing is happen after using JSLink.

Comment: It will be much quicker (if you're comfortable) to debug this using the IE developer toolbar. Setup breakpoints and see where it is failing.

Comment: First of all you are loading jQuery twice

Comment: Yea loading twice, if the local don't work the other will, never used IE developer toolbar before.

Comment: It might make sense to use 1.10.2 for all scenarios... 1.6.2 is from 2011

Comment: Quick Tip: You can load multiple JS files in the JSLink field by separating them by a pipe character ( | ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always great to see the `hideFiledTemplate` typo..

You do not need a 90 KB library and all the loading hassles to hide a Filed .. ehm Field

```
(function(){
  var hideField="<span class='csrHiddenField'></span>";

  var overrides = {};
  overrides.Templates = {}; 
  overrides.Templates.Fields = {
    "DueDate": {
      "NewForm": hideField,
      "EditForm": hideField
    }
  };  
  overrides.Templates.OnPostRender = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(".csrHiddenField").forEach(function(field){
      GetAncestor( field , 'TR' ).style.display='none';
    });
  };

  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrides);
})();
```

Notes:

- Overrides are Strings, so no need to define a `function` and return a String
- No need to declare a separate function (OnPostRender) if you only call it once
- This is not MDS save, use [the Cisar CSR editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en) to get the MDS save boilerplate
- GetAncestor is defined by SharePoint core code

#### And Dylan Christy has an even better way:

[CSR Hide a field on form but not with jQUery](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168898/csr-hide-a-field-on-form-but-not-with-jquery)

**which you would have found had you searched 'csr hide field' before asking!!!**

Comment: With jQuery or not it's not working in this case, my bad with the **csr hide field**, sorry, but i'm missing something and i can't find the problem, it's not working.

Comment: Use the Cisar Chrome extension, paste this code, and use the correct Internal fieldname (note: the currect Cisar 1.3 version has a bug, Andrei is working on a fix as we speak) In the mean time set the JSLink on the Form webpart by hand.. when you then ope Cisar it will work

Comment: The console shows no error, but Chrome shows **Error occured when saving file**. Thank you very much for helping me.